# How would I implement a cascaded collection of DropDowns with least possible code-behind?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a layout of six DevExpress ComboBoxEdit controls. Only the top one is not filtered, then each one below the other filtered on the selection in the one above it. I'm convinced that if I use the correct collections in my model, and bindings in my view, I can achieve this without code behind. How could I go about this?

I'm thinking that because. e.g. the top most combo is bound to `Department` objects, each of which has a `Gangs` collection, and the next dropdown is "Gang", I can use a relative source or something, to always have the "Gang" dropdown bound to the `Gangs` collection of the selected department.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, each ComboBox is dependent on the one located above it?

I would imagine you could accomplish most of this by binding the `SelectedItem` of the ComboBox to the one located above it. This will eliminate the majority of your code-behind.

Comment: I want to limit the `Items` collection in each ComboBoxes based on the `SelectedItem` in the one above it, not just 'synchronize' the ComboBoxes' selections.